# Replace substring with its exact length of another character

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a substring within a string with an exact number of other characters.

Example:

**Input:** Hello There, General Kenobie!

**Output:** xxxxx There, xxxxxxx Kenobie!

I can get this to work if I replace it with a preset string:

```js
    const text = "'Hello' There, 'General' Kenobie!"
    const pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/g;
    console.log(text.replace(pattern, "xxx"));
```

**Output:** xxx There, xxx Kenobie!

What am I missing wrapping my head around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are using a hard-coded string of `'xxx'` as your replacement string.  So, that's what you are seeing... the string(s) replaced with `'xxx'`.

The `.replace()` method actually supports a *function* as the replacement, instead of a string, so that's what you need here.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

```js
const text = "'Hello' There, 'General' Kenobie!"
const pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/g;

const newText = text.replace(pattern, (str, m) => 'x'.repeat(m.length));

console.log(newText);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know `replace` supported that.

Comment: I didn't know the `repeat( )` was a thing :p

Answer (score 0):

You can always loop through the matches and replace each separately.

```js
let text = "'Hello' There, 'General' Kenobie!"
const pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/g;

let array1;
while ((array1 = pattern.exec(text)) !== null) {
  wrap = array1[0][0];
  text = text.replace(array1[0],wrap + "x".repeat(array1[0].length-2) + wrap);
}

console.log(text)
```